# Automation of daily file creation

Tags: bash, automation, power-automate

Trying to figure out how to go about automating a daily folder creation named as the date of the creation. Then within that folder, 3 more folders are created. Within 2 of those folders, 2 more folders are created.

I've been Googling a way to do this with power automate or creating a .bat script but can't find anything closely related to this. [Refrence-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3DFF.png)

Comment: `mkdir -p $(date +%F)/{Trailers,Beds}/{Weld,Finish Line} $(date +%F)/Pre-Ship`

Comment: @jordanm Seems we have to quote like `"Finish Line"`

Comment: You're right, I copied and pasted the wrong test I ran

Comment: YES!!! This worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Any recommendation in regards to batch scripting to learn from? Like a Udemy course or in-depth tutorial? There are a lot of scripts I'd like to learn how to create and use but very little resources available.

Answer (score 0):

In a .bat script you could use something like this and use Task Scheduler to run it once a day:

```
@echo off
md "%Date:/=-%\Trailers\Weld"
md "%Date:/=-%\Trailers\Finish Line"
md "%Date:/=-%\Beds\Weld"
md "%Date:/=-%\Beds\Finish Line"
md "%Date:/=-%\Pre-Ship"
```